# How to return NodeJS HTTP Request errors without waiting for timeout?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application based on NodeJS/Express and AngularJS which talks to a, application server via REST API. In the event that the application server is not running, I would like to immediately return an error to the AngularJS client that the calls are failing.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(input);

var postHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
};

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 7777,
  path: path,
  method: method,
  headers: postHeaders
};

var appServerRequest = http.request(options, function(appServerResult) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + appServerResult.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(appServerResult.headers));
  appServerResult.setEncoding('utf8');
  var responseDataString = '';
  appServerResult.on('data', function(chunk) {
    responseDataString += chunk;
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  appServerResult.on('end', function() {
    callback(responseDataString);
  });
  appServerResult.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('** Result ERROR in appServerResponse');
    console.log(e);
  });
});

appServerRequest.on('response', function(response) {
  console.log('Response: ' + response);
});

appServerRequest.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('** Request ERROR in appServerRequest');
  console.log(e);
});

appServerRequest.write(jsonObject);
appServerRequest.end();
```

As you can see, I'm listening to the 'error' events on both the Request and Response objects. When a call is made and the application server is not running, the Request error handler is called as expected. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to take that error and return it to the client. A response object is eventually returned, but only after the timeout expires. It seems like there should be a way to return a Response and specify an appropriate HTTP Status code as soon as I detect the error. I could do it if I had a response object (of course), but I don't get one until the timeout expires.

I know I must be missing something simple, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention you're using `express`.  Simply call [`res.send(500)`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) to end the request with an error code (in this case `500`)

Comment: Don't I need a Response object on which to call .send()?

Comment: Express provides it in the call to your route handler.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was missing. Thanks!